# Need fast algorithm to find mutually exclusive networks(relations) from trillions of relationship records

Tags: algorithm, pyspark, bigdata

I am explaining my problem with a hypothetical table with two columns(col1, col2) like this:

```
col1   col2
A <--> B
A <--> C
E <--> F
B <--> D   
E <--> G
```

This table is in a file. In the above case I would like to divide this into mutually exclusive relationship files. So, the results for above table would be two files(tables):

```
col1   col2
A <--> B
A <--> C    
B <--> D
```

and

```
col1   col2   
E <--> F     
E <--> G
```

The real file has trillions of unique records (relations) and I want to divide it into mutually exclusive relationship files. Need help with any smart algorithms. I am using pyspark to read the table from parquet file. So, any pyspark code would be very nice but not necessary(algorithm is more important).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Comment: I think you're looking for the *connected components* in the graph (which you call a network).  This is a much studied problem, I believe there are solutions with linear complexity.  You shouldn't have much difficulty finding help from your favourite search engine.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with google but didn't know actual terms for search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "mutually exclusive" you probably mean not having a node in common. This problem is known as the enumeration of connected components in a graph. You can address it with the Union-Find technique.

To every node, you will associate a link to another node that belongs to the same component. When taking a new relation into account, make one of the members link to the other.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure for details. 
This process is fast and you can accelerate it by so-called path-compression techniques.

In the end, every component has a single node that is not linked to any  other and it is not a big deal to list all components and the nodes they include.

Steps in the processing of the given example could be

```
A -> B
C -> A -> B
C -> A -> B, E -> F
C -> A -> B -> D, E -> F
C -> A -> B -> D, E -> F -> G
```

(the fact that you get linear lists is purely accidental).

Answer (score 0):

Using Spark, it's very fast. For those who are dealing with big data it can be useful:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, size, length
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "32g") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "32g") \
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "12") \
    .config("spark.local.dir", "~/mytmp") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "graphframes:graphframes:0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11") \
    .getOrCreate()
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '32g')
sc = spark.sparkContext

df = spark.read.parquet("my_table_file.parquet")
df.registerTempTable("mytable")
# df has two columns : col1 and col2. Similar to hypothetical table presented in my question

v = spark.sql("select col1 as id from mytable union select col2 as id from mytable ")
e = spark.sql("select col1 as src, col2 as dst from mytable")
sc.setCheckpointDir("~/cc_checkpoint")

from graphframes import *
g = GraphFrame(v, e)
connected = g.connectedComponents()
connected.registerTempTable("mytable_connected_components")
connected.select("component").distinct().count()
```